# Measurable selection of curves in length spaces

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a length space. 
This means a metric space $(X,d)$ where $d$ is defined via a length functional $\mathcal{L}$ and a set of admissibles curves $\mathcal{A}$ as follows:
$$
d(x,y) 
=
\inf \{ \mathcal{L}(\gamma) | \gamma \in [x\rightarrow y]_{\mathcal{A}}\}
$$

where $[x\rightarrow y]_{\mathcal{A}}$ are those curves in $\mathcal{A}$ beginning at $x$ and terminating at $y$.

My question is about a measurable selection of nearly optimal curves.

Given $\epsilon>0$ and a basepoint $x_0$ does there exist a measurable selection $x \mapsto \gamma_x$ of curves in $\mathcal{A}$ so that $\gamma \in [x_0\rightarrow x]$ and $\mathcal{L}(\gamma_x) \leq d(x_0,x) + \epsilon$?

That is, can we make a measurable selection from the sets
$$\{ \gamma \in [x_0\rightarrow x]\mid \mathcal{L}(\gamma) \leq d(x_0,x) + \epsilon\}$$
?

My first issue is that I don't even know what the sigma algebra on the curves should be. I consulted some theorems on measurable selection; it would seem reasonable that the sets above should be closed in some topology, and then consider the Borel sigma algebra on this topology. But then I ran into another issue of (1) whether $\mathcal{L}$ should be continuous on the $\mathcal{A}$ (which seems strong) and (2) my theorem on measurable selection required the target space $\mathcal{A}$ to be metric.

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but what is a length functional?  Does $X$ already have some other structure on it that lets you define length for admissible curves?

Comment: @Callus I am considering a length functional as in the book "A Course in
Metric Geometry" by Burago et. al (see Chapter 2). Essentially, $\mathcal{L}$ is a real valued function on curves satisfying some continuity properties, invariance under reparameterizations, and the property that the length of the concatenation of curves is the sum of the lengths of the indivdual curves.